# To pool controls or not?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, paired-data, blocking

I have a data set containing measurements from cells that have had 200 different perturbations applied to them. Each perturbation has been applied in duplicate. Because there are so many perturbations, not all could be carried out at once, so there is not just a single pair of control (unperturbed) samples, but several. Each perturbation is matched to a control, and each control is matched to between 1 and 50 perturbations.

To complicate matters, all this was done in two different types of cell.

None of this was under my control, the experiment was carried out like this, and we have obtained the data later.

The question is, is it better to:

1. Test each perturbation against its match control. This would be a 2x2 t-test, which presumably would have very little power, particularly after multiple testing correction.
2. Test each perturbation against a pool of all the controls.
3. Build a giant model with 200 different perturbation coefficients and 47 different control/batch coefficients. Try to disentangle what is happening with post-hoc tests? Note that in this case, batch is completely nested in cell type, and perturbation is completely nested in batch, with the exception of the control level for perturbation (which is only 2 samples).

I assume that the which is correct will have something to do with the ratio of the variance explained by the difference between different batches, the replicate to replicate variance, and the effect size of each perturbation (which is, hopefully, very heterogeneous). TO this end, performing an anova on `~ batch + perturbation + perturbation:cell_type` give very significant values for all the terms.

Any rules or rules of thumb to work out the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

For option 1, you wouldn't proceed with a set of *t*-tests. When you have several samples to compare against a control, "[Dunnett's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test) takes into consideration the special structure of comparing treatment against control, yielding narrower confidence intervals."

You should be able to gain substantial power via something similar to a combination of options 2 and 3: not with all control values pooled as in option 2, or with all batches considered fixed effects as in option 3, but with `batch` treated as a random effect in a [mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mixed-model/info). That would allow for batch-to-batch differences in control values, which would be modeled as a single Gaussian distribution (one parameter to fit, the variance) instead of as 47 fixed effects. That's often called "partial pooling," and seems to be what these data call for.

You will still have to deal with 200 treatments applied to 2 different cell types, but the above will at least simplify the handling of multiple batches. If you proceed with a mixed model, the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) has "dunnettx" and "mvt" multiple-comparison options that do Dunnett corrections in a way that respects the mixed-model structure.